# Import contacts from outlook to iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, xcode, outlook, ios4, synchronization

I want to know if it is possible to import contacts from outlook to iPhone through code. I want to implement a sync functionality in which a user can import contacts from their Outlook into their iPhones. If so then what approach has to be followed.

Comment: By outlook do you mean the mail application on their phone or do you mean the mail application on the mac, or do you mean actually Microsoft Outlook?

Comment: see my ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816102/retrieving-outlook-contacts-in-iphone/8817225#8817225

Answer (score 1):

There are two modes of sync.

1. Through iTunes and the desktop. To my knowledge, I dont think its possible programmatically to invoke iTunes and make it sync, as it rightly should be. So, there is not much left to do there.
2. If you are looking to sync with an existing MS Exchange server account, then there are not many choices out there but to implement the way [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816102/retrieving-outlook-contacts-in-iphone/8817225#8817225) seems to point out.

However, if you are bit lucky, you might be able to get it to work with a bit of poking 
-around with IMAP. There are are a few libraries out there that you could possibly repurpose. Unfortunately, there are no straight forward solutions, that atleast i kno of, for achieving this as yet and this could possibly be the easiest route. One such lib is : [Remail](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/). Another point to remember is that some c libs may also support iphone/cocoa and its not a bad idea to watch out for some of them.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Things are going to be different depending on which version of outlook you are using and the email server that it is connecting to. I am assuming that you are not connecting to an exchange server and that you dont want to use iTunes so your best bet to get the contacts to an iPhone is going to be a desktop app that connects to a webservice that will then sync with an iPhone app that can dump the contacts into an address book. You will have to write an exporter for your version of outlook (2003, 2007, 2010, 2011 are all still widely used) so it may just be easier to have your user open a gmail account and then use it to push the contacts to the phone.

It may seem convoluted and but the only official ways to sync your contacts are going to be through iTunes, icloud, active sync or google sync. I may just be having trouble understanding why you are trying to reinvent the wheel here so perhaps you could explain more of what you are trying to do here.