# Retrieving Outlook contacts in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to import all the outlook contacts through application. Is there any way to do this? please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by implementing Microsoft exchange server protocol. 
[MSDN.Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) - this link contains a document named MS-ASWBXML. You have to write an encoder for wbxml then you have to implement the EAS-protocol on top o wbxml.
[other useful link](http://www.w3.org/TR/wbxml/)
[Exchange ActiveSync Deployment Scenario](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=active%20sync%20apple%20documentation&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_EAS.pdf&ei=-VANT7S4N4PJrAe01pSpBA&usg=AFQjCNFkFbb2FIdDeEx_g3vBRmHULQbUHA&sig2=aepoXyVDGeZkspyG6qy23g&cad=rja)
[more ref](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=active%20sync%20apple%20documentation&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFUQFjAG&url=http://www.icewarp.com/download/documentation/server/mobility/V10%2520Exchange%2520ActiveSync%2520Guide.pdf&ei=-VANT7S4N4PJrAe01pSpBA&usg=AFQjCNF5w0XpnLmEvyu2Bsk2J5xBASVDcQ&sig2=P5ngT3BK4mQgBI2Cb0gyXQ&cad=rja)